# First Access date or Enrolled date for a specific course

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I would really appreciate any help with this dilemma !

I need a report that just lists out the exact date when a user has enrolled into a specific course (or First access). i.e. if the user is enrolled in two courses on the site on two different dates, I need the exact date when the user commenced each course. (either enrolled or access)

I believe the role assignment date for the specific course should do the trick, but how do I get the 'role assigned' date for all users of a course ?

I tried setting up a SQL query as below. It gives me the list of users, the courses they are enrolled into etc.

However, it is giving me the same creation / access date for all the course - which is the site level date. How do I get the course level start or role assignment date ?

I would really appreciate any help. I am really at my wits end !

```
user2.firstname AS Firstname,
user2.lastname AS Lastname,
user2.email AS Email,
user2.city AS City,

DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(user2.firstaccess), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS 'Firstaccess',
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(user2.timecreated), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS 'Timecreated',
course.fullname AS Course
,(SELECT shortname FROM prefix_role WHERE id=en.roleid) AS ROLE
,(SELECT name FROM prefix_role WHERE id=en.roleid) AS RoleName
FROM prefix_course AS course 
JOIN prefix_enrol AS en ON en.courseid = course.id
JOIN prefix_user_enrolments AS ue ON ue.enrolid = en.id
JOIN prefix_user AS user2 ON ue.userid = user2.id
```

- Moodle version 3.5 -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get first course access in moodle 3+. This action is not logged anymore, you can only get last access.

As for enrolment time (TimeCreated), try this:

`SELECT u.username, u.lastname, u.firstname, c.fullname, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(ue.timecreated), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS 'Timecreated' FROM prefix_user_enrolments ue LEFT JOIN prefix_enrol e ON (ue.enrolid = e.id) LEFT JOIN prefix_course c ON (e.courseid = c.id) LEFT JOIN prefix_user u ON (ue.userid = u.id)`

First access actually makes no sense, since enrolment time will always be the earliest date between two. Even if user uses self-enrolment. Guest course access is probably the only exception, but it doesn't require user id, so it will make your report inconsistent anyway. So 99% of the time you would want to check upon user enrolments exactly, and the earliest date is always enrolment time.

If your moodle version is less than 3, you may get first access via `prefix_log`

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the first access to the course by querying the mdl_logstore_standard_log for the event "\core\event\course viewed" eventname.

```
SELECT * FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log
WHERE eventname LIKE "%course_viewed%"
AND userid=##
```

timecreated is the specific field you're looking for

If a user is not enrolled in the course and they view the enrollment page (for that course), the course viewed event is not fired. So you shouldn't get any false positives.